# How to get the x and y intercept in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have scoured the internet and can't find a python command to find the x and y intercepts of a curve on matplotlib. Is there a command that exists? or is there a much easier way that is going over my head? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

Nimrodian.

Comment: You just mean where x and y are equal in value, right? `for x, y in zip(x_values, y_values): if x == y: print(x, y)`

Comment: That didn't work for me dude: https://gyazo.com/3eac13d35d9d0f3fdf544d9e3c87f0e1  I want to be able to get the coordinates of the point at 10 on the x axis. If you get what I mean?

Comment: Right, I don't know what I was thinking. I see now what you mean. So then you'll want to test `if y == 0 or x == 0` instead of `if x == y`

Comment: Okay yeah, it seems it is alot simpler than I imagined. Thanks for the help man!

Comment: Great, I'll submit the answer. Please mark it as helpful if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x, y in zip(x_values, y_values):
    if x == 0 or y == 0:
        print(x, y)
```

Comment: This is not a good general solution. It only works if you have an x value or y value that is exactly equal to 0.

Comment: But I will have a value that is equal to zero, because I am plotting trajectories of projectiles, and they always hit the ground.

Comment: @A.Kot -- In such a case if a value is close to 0, but not exactly 0 `math.isclose` might be appropriate if that's the desired behavior. However, in cases where x or y approaches 0 asymptotically, you probably don't want to mark it an intercept. Your answer works fine as well, and I might have offered the same solution if I had seen numpy appear in OP's question.

Answer (score 6):

Use this. Much faster:

```
slope, intercept = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

`x` and `y` are arrays (or lists) of your coordinates. The third parameter sets the degree of the fitting polynomial.  In the case of a first degree polynomial here, it will find coefficients to fit the following function: **y = Ax + b**.  The parameters A and B are the slope and y-intercept, respectively.

See more details on this routine here:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html

Comment: I am getting this error dude: TypeError: expected 1D vector for x

Comment: x should be your list of all x values